# how to create QTableview cell hover function

Tags: python, pyqt5, hover, qtableview

I created a table with QTableview. I tried to add mouse hover function (if I keep mouse on particular cell) to change cursor style. I couldn't able to fine any inbuilt function mouse hover connect function in QTableview. so i used mouse `table.entered.connect(on_entered)` for changing cursor. leave function not available. so I am facing below issue showed in picture. hand cursor change in cell(1,1) but not changing back to arrow when leave cell(1,1)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

data=[[1,1],[1,2],['a','b']]

class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data,header_labels=None):
        super().__init__();self._data = data;self.header_labels=header_labels

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
    def rowCount(self, index):return len(self._data)
    def columnCount(self, index):return len(self._data[0])
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if self.header_labels==None:self.header_labels=range(len(self._data[0]))
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Horizontal:return self.header_labels[section]
        return QAbstractTableModel.headerData(self, section, orientation, role)

def on_entered(index):
    if index.row()==1 and index.column()==1: table.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))
    else:table.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.CursorShape.ArrowCursor))
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
vl=QVBoxLayout(window)

searchbar = QLineEdit()
table=QTableView()
proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
model = TableModel(data)
proxy_model.setSourceModel(model)
table.setModel(proxy_model)

table.entered.connect(on_entered)
table.setMouseTracking(True)
table.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
table.setFocusPolicy(Qt.FocusPolicy.NoFocus)

vl.addWidget(table)
t=TableModel(data[1:],data[0])
proxy_model.setSourceModel(t)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass the table, override [`mouseMoveEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#mouseMoveEvent) and check the index at the mouse position using [`indexAt`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#indexAt).

Since mouse interaction could be happening during a mouse movement, you should only set the cursor if *no* buttons are being pressed. The `mouseTracking` property is still required.

```
class CursorShapeTable(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)
        if not event.buttons():
            index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
            if index.row() == 1 and index.column() == 1:
                self.setCursor(Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor)
            else:
                self.unsetCursor()
```

Comment: this is working fine for mouse cursor format. in the same way, if I want to change cell background color instead of cursor format. which option need to choose? how to reset previous cell format?

Comment: @Viswa mouse cursor and cell formats are completely different things. If you want to change the way a cell is displayed when mouse is hovered then you need to use a custom item delegate, but that would be off topic for this question, so I suggest you to: 1. do some research and studying on Qt item delegates, and 2. eventually ask a separate question.